# How to use Vue directive in external file and import into components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuelidate, vue-directives

I'm using Vuelidate in a project and when the user types something I set a timeout to wait for validation.  I tried to use mixins and it was successful, but for good habits I need to create a Vue directive without registering it globally, and use that in some components.

I created an external file `directives/delayTouch.js` (I tried to export only `const` with `export const` but Vue forces me to use `export default`)

```js
const delayTouch = {
  inserted ($v) {
    const touchMap = new WeakMap()

    $v.$reset()
    if (touchMap.has($v)) {
      clearTimeout(touchMap.get($v))
    }

    touchMap.set($v, setTimeout($v.$touch, 1000))
  }
}

export default delayTouch
```

And I imported into my component:

```html
<template>
  <TextField
    v-delay-touch="$v.data.name"
    :v="$v.data.name"
    v-model.trim="$v.data.name.$model"
    id="name"
    label="Nome da campanha"
  />
</template>
<script>
import delayTouch from '@/directives/delayTouch'
    
export default {
  directives: { delayTouch }
}
</script>
```

In param (`$v`) I receive the HTML correctly but I'm still receiving the error `$v.reset is not a function`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Directive hooks receive [4 arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments):

- `el`, `binding`, `vnode`, and `oldVnode`

So the first argument to the `inserted` hook is the HTML element, not the `$v` object.  To bring a component property into the directive, use the directive's `vnode` argument, getting the component's `context` through it:

```js
inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
  const $v = vnode.context.$v;
  ...
}
```

Wherever you want to access the element in the directive, use `el`.